# Repetition of logic in commands and queries

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Our architecture is divided in commands and queries its not fully CQRS but we try keep those things separated. Both use the same database. Let say that we have requirement that says:
User may send message only to:

1. its close friends who have messaging system enabled
2. its close friends who are premium users
3. to any administrator on contact list

We check those requirements when user tries to send message to a person, so domain rules are secured. However now we need to show list of possible message recipients to user and all of those rules need to be repeated on query side. And that bothers us.

Is this violation of DRY or is it ok? If new rule will be introduced it must be added in two places. Is there any nice way to handle such situations?

Comment: The problem is that you are using one database and so your are not fully-CQRS. You could try to create a Read-DB using Views on the Write-DB so that the reading part is only queries on those view.

Comment: @ema Do you mean view in database? Then I will have repetition of those rules inside this view. I thought about creating denormalized table but I am not sure how should I implement data replication. Should I use domain events or database triggers? Still there will be two places where those rules would need to be maintained

Comment: View in the database is an option, then the "logic" will be hidden in the query that builds the view. If you can create a different set of table for read-only data you can consume the domain events to denormalize the data in that tables, so that the read-concern will be only "SELECT * FROM Table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to share the code. If you're in one database, than a simple view will probably do the trick. The query to limit potential addressees cannot be authoritative; only the command can do the final verification. The query just helps the user. The command would execute under some known transaction boundary to ensure the rule is followed.

Comment: My man has it exactly right IMO: Make sure the command throws exceptions if a rule is violated.  You cannot guarantee the command won't throw an exception because you have no idea how stale the data is on the user's screen even if the query is 100% correct.

Comment: @JoshKodroff Thats right, we can't be 100% sure, so our commands throw exceptions if rule is violated. But for example if there is few thousand of users and messages might be sent only to few of them then query should return as smallest set of users as it is possible. In order to do that some knowledge about command rules is required. If query/view try to repeat this logic then there might be problems when new rules will be added.

Comment: @Machet You just either have to live with that duplication, or put that logic in a shared place where both the read and write side can see it.  But remember: queries are not the authoritative answer for what can and cannot be done - the command handlers are.

Answer (score 0):

> "We check those requirements when user tries to send message to a
>   person, so domain rules are secured. However now we need to show list
>   of possible message recipients to user and all of those rules need to
>   be repeated on query side. And that bothers us."

How is that going to be repeated if you are using the same database for both domain and read models? Even if you are using one database for everything, on your domain and read model handlers you should abstract that with read only repositories. Also in relation to your mention about DRY, you will have that a lot in a CQRS architecture, since one of the aims is to be able to retrieve that faster without the need to do huge queries, so you will end with data repeated across diferent models.